# how to wait for promise response in delaywhen operator using interceptors

Tags: angular, typescript, http, angular-http-interceptors

I am working on to handle http failure and trying to show prompt for retry request to user. I am facing issue to handle promise response in delayWhen opertor. Below is my code

```
  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        console.log(request);                         
            return next.handle(request).pipe(
              timeout(15000),
              retryWhen(errors => {
                return errors.pipe(

                delayWhen((error:any) => {                        

                    if(error.name == 'TimeoutError' || !navigator.onLine || error.status == 0 ){
                    return from(this.promptForRetry(error, 'Error','Request taking more time than expected, please check your connection'));
                }                    
                    else
                    return this.handleError(error);
                  })
                )
              }),
              tap((event: HttpEvent<any>) => {
                  if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
                      console.log(event);
                  }
              }),
              catchError((err) => {                 
                  return this.handleError(err);
              })
          );
        }
```

and here is my prompt function:

```
   async promptForRetry(error, title, msg){
        let retry_subject = new Subject();        
        let retry = await this.alertCtrl.create({
            header:title,
            message: msg,
            buttons: [
                {
                    text: 'No',
                    handler: () => {                        
                        retry_subject.error( error );
                        retry_subject.complete();
                        retry.dismiss();
                        return false;
                    }
                },
                {
                    text: 'Retry',
                    handler: () => {                        
                        retry_subject.next( 1 );
                        retry_subject.complete();
                        retry.dismiss();
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            ]
        });
       await retry.present();
       await retry.onWillDismiss();              
       return retry_subject;
    }
```

whatever I select retry or no button from prompt, it again prompts.

please help how to handle response in delaywhen operator

Comment: So `this.alertCtrl.create` returns a promise? Is there no way it can use observables?

Comment: ok, I get it working by changing code from
```return retry_subject;```

to 

``` return retry_subject.toPromise(); ```